# Create multiple HTMLs for the same markdown files (Hugo docuapi)

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, hugo

I am using Docuapi theme with Hugo.

The docuapi theme combines all markdown files into one and generates a single HTML file.
I am using a Consent Management system to display a cookie consent banner.
The site is deployed using Cloudfront CDN.

I want to display the consent banner only for the requests coming from a certain region.

Is it possible to generate two different html files out of hugo for the same markdown files, with the same URL structure, and load them depending on which region the request is coming from?

I can setup my CDN to access different files based on the request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reuse content easily by doing this in your partial/layout/shortcode:

```
{{ with $.Site.GetPage 'yourmarkdownfile.md' }}{{ .Content }}{{ end }}
```

Can that be a starting point for a solution?